# Followhyperlink in "click" event environment to open a specific filename .pdf

Tags: .htaccess, ms-access-2016

Working in access db form frm_Rest which has a couple of controls txt_Shop and txt_Stat with a command button btn_PDF.

Whenever a user makes a credit entry for file **CR-Acct** the name will appear in txt_Shop and the credit amount will show in txt_Stat, the btn_PDF alerts user to submit a pdf CreditRequest (Sumbission of pdf request is NOT always necessary). If user decides to submit a pdf creditrequest, and btn_PDF is clicked a popup asks if user wants to create a pdf request, if YES or NO the selected action proceeds as demanded. Yes answer should open the pdf creditrequest from the stored **location** while No terminates. The address of the stored location is as follows: **T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf CR** and these are some of the files in pdf Requests available for entries CR-Finance, CR-Bank, CR-Home, CR-Acct.

Among several files, I need to be able to open the related filename currently being processed in **txt_Shop**.

I have tried using the two followHyperlinks below. The first one gets me to the folder without opening the desired filename, and the second one pops out and error msg "Cannot Open the specified file". I need to be able to get whatever filename (CR-Finance, CR-Bank, CR-Home, CR-Acct) that is in **txt_Shop** control.

FollowHyperlink "T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf CR"

FollowHyperlink "T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf CR" &txt_Shop.pdf"

Please Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.